# Determine the number of Visible Objects in a window Powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder.net

I am new to PowerBuilder,

I put 10 objects in a window, and visibility of 9 object is false by default.

when I click a text/data on a 'ddlb' some object may appear or get visible.
example. 
     2 textboxes , 2 buttons and 1 'ddlb' must get visible

my questions is, is there a way to determine the number of object control  in a window that is being visible?

hope  someone could help.. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the window control array and check the visible status of each control (literally windowobject) there:

```
int li_count, li_index, li_visiblecount = 0

li_count = UpperBound(this.control)
FOR li_index = 1 TO li_count
  IF this.control[li_index].visible THEN
    li_visiblecount ++
  END IF
NEXT
```

However, what you should really consider doing if you are using PowerBuilder is using a DataWindow with controls on it rather than separate windows controls.

Comment: just an idea for that question. my main goal here  is to save all the update DataWindows that are  being visible. based on the selected item in another datawindow.